# JPA - Changing a reference to an existing (but detached) entity causes a duplicate to be inserted

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, entitymanager

I have two entities with a uni-directional many-to-one relationship:

- Many `Bar`s have one `Foo`

When I try to update a managed `Bar` instance by changing its `Foo` to an existing detached `Foo` instance, the flush to the DB fails.

I use facades (`FooFacade` & `BarFacade`) to create and modify the entities. Here is my test code:

```
public void test() {
    FooFacade fooFacade = (FooFacade) lookupEJB(FooFacade.class);
    BarFacade barFacade = (BarFacade) lookupEJB(BarFacade.class);

    Foo originalFoo = fooFacade.createFoo();    // returned entity is detatched
    Foo newFoo = fooFacade.createFoo();         // returned entity is detatched

    Bar bar = barFacade.createBar(originalFoo); // returned entity is detatched

    barFacade.changeFoo(bar.getId(), newFoo);
}
```

This code will cause the following SQL error:

> The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key
>   value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified
>   by 'SQL130321134048610' defined on 'FOO'.

Eclipselink is trying to insert `newFoo` when flushing the change of `bar`, even though it already exists!

However, the fact that the `newFoo` instance is detached should make no difference - see the relevent part of the [EJB persistence spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) (section 3.2.3, page 50) in **bold** below:

> The semantics of the flush operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
>
>   - For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value
>       cascade=PERSIST or cascade= ALL, the persist operation is applied to
>       Y.
>   - For any entity Y referenced by a relationship from X, where the relationship to Y has not been annotated with the cascade element
>       value cascade=PERSIST or cascade= ALL:
>
>     - If Y is new or removed, an IllegalStateException will be thrown by the flush operation (and the transaction rolled back) or the
>         transaction commit will fail.
>     - **If Y is detached, the semantics depend upon the ownership of the relationship. If X owns the relationship, any changes to the
>         relationship are synchronized with the database**; otherwise, if Y owns
>         the relationships, the behavior is undefined.
> - If X is a removed entity, it is removed from the database. No cascade options are   relevant.

Can anybody help explain why this doesn't seem to work? I cannot find an existing eclipselink bug report. I have some code below, and the technologies are:

- EclipseLink (testing using the embedded Glassfish EJB container)
- Derby (for testing this issue - in production I use MS SQL and it also fails)

Thanks!

> **Please note:** I understand that I could make this work by
>
> 1. merging the detached `Foo` into the same Persistence Context that is used when updating `bar`, then
> 2. setting that merged instance of `foo` on the `bar`.
>
> However, this is not the approach I wish to take in my application.

***Update 1:** I've included the part of the JPA spec which suggests this should work*

***Update 2:** Simplified the example scenario*

### Entities

```
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name="test_generator", table="SEQUENCE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName="SEQ_VALUE", pkColumnValue="TEST_SEQUENCE")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="test_generator")
    private int id;

    public int getId() {return this.id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="test_generator")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Foo foo;

    public int getId() {return this.id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public Foo getFoo() {return this.foo;}
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {this.foo = foo;}

}
```

### The Facades

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class FooFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CurriculumManagementSystem")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Foo createFoo() {
        Foo newFoo = new Foo();

        em.persist(newFoo);

        return newFoo;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class BarFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CurriculumManagementSystem")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Bar createBar(Foo parent) {
        Bar newBar = new Bar();

        newBar.setFoo(parent);

        em.persist(newBar);

        return newBar;
    }

    public void changeFoo(int barID, Foo detachedFoo) {
        Bar bar = (Bar) em.find(Bar.class, barID);

        bar.setFoo(detachedFoo);

        // when this method exits, the transaction completes
        // and any changes are flushed to the DB.

        // instead of only updating the Bar table by changing the
        // foreign key reference to the detachedFoo's ID, elipselink
        // tries to insert the detachedFoo as a new row in the
        // Foo table!
    }
```

Comment: "I load the newCategory with a transaction-scoped Entity Manager in a new transaction - it is detached" ?? Not detached until the associated transaction is commited. Do you give this instance reference to the `content` object you persist ? As it comes from a different em the extended one may not recognize it as an existing entity

Comment: Thanks for responding @Gab. Yes, the transaction-scoped EM resides inside a `Singleton` configured to use container-managed transactions - so the transaction commits when the newCategory entity is returned to the client. The entity is detached. **"Do you give this instance reference to the content object you persist?"** Yes. **"As it comes from a different em the extended one may not recognize it as an existing entity"** This appears to be the case, however my understanding is that it shouldn't matter because I'm only flushing the owner of the relationship - JPA should ignore the inverse.

Comment: @Gab I reworked the example code to make the transaction and persistence context boundaries clearer, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Something related to equals method maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to a bug in EclipseLink:

> [Any changes that reference detached object will cause detached to be inserted](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300108)

This has been fixed in version 2.4.0. It was reported in version 1.1.3.

As of writing, the version of EclipseLink distributed with the latest version of Glassfish (3.1.2) is 2.3.2, so I will either have to wait for a future release of Glassfish, or provide the newer EclipseLink libraries with my application.

For the time being, I will wait and use the merge workaround I described in my original post. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me with this issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are corrupting your objects by mixing managed and detached objects.  You should not mix the two.

If you want to change the reference of an object, you should do a find() or getReference() for the new reference in the same persistence context (EntityManager/transaction).

You also need to correctly maintain bi-directional relationships.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the reference to the JPA spec where it states that mixing managed and detached objects should not be a problem in this case. Could this be a bug in eclipselink? I can't find any such bug report. Thanks for reminding me about bi-directional relationship maintenance.

Comment: Although I've now modified the example scenario to be uni-directional to prove to myself that this had no impact on the issue - and it does not.